# New row is not reflected in database while using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

```
public IHttpActionResult PostCountry(Country country)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Country.Add(country);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = country.CountyID }, country);
}
```

[image]

Data is saving successfully but not displaying in database.

Here I attached the screen

[image]